# Определить качество JPG картинки

Tags: python, opencv, pil

Есть задача - отсортировать качественные фотки от некачественных. Качество определяется дизайнером на глаз по чёткости, зернистости.

Существует ли способ с помощью Python (PIL, или OpenCV) определить зернистость, или размытость фото?

Подойдёт любой способ автоматизировать хотя бы часть этой работы. Отсеять явно качественные (Perfect Qty) от остальных, а с остальными потом разбираться. Или наоборот.

Пробовал определять качество по степени сжатия JPG. Но даже с большим сжатием (60% и меньше) попадаются фото Perfect Qty, и с маленьким сжатием (90% и больше) фото Bad Qty. И этот способ совсем не помог.

Comment: https://www.machinelearningmastery.ru/automatic-image-quality-assessment-in-python-391a6be52c11/ большая статья -> которая полностью описывает и решает вашу задачу

Comment: Гуглите `no-reference image quality assessment`

Comment: https://github.com/krshrimali/No-Reference-Image-Quality-Assessment-using-BRISQUE-Model

Comment: Да, без машинного обучения тут никак, думаю ))

Comment: Попробовал метод BRISQUE IQA по ссылке выше. Сортирует, но очень не точно. Задачу не решило.